# Advanced Parse server setup on AWS for a developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm currently trying to create a parse server on AWS using their suggested path of Elastic Beanstalk to simplify the process. There is a very primitive guide here:
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk

I was able to get this running but I now have a few issues: 
1) I am unable to use EB CLI to connect to my instance. The section:
**ADVANCED: Updating and Deploying your code** states to simply call:
`eb init` and pick your application that you created. Then call `eb labs download` This only returns an error that no environment has been setup. I try to use `eb list` so I can call `eb use XXX` but nothing is returned.

2) I want to install the Parse dashboard but have no idea how to log in so I can call npm install.

Any guidance or resources to read on these topics would be very helpful. Even an outline of the steps. I've spent the last 48 hours straight on trying to get this up and running without any luck.

Thanks,

David

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you, but you should know that on Elastic Beanstalk you never want to login directly and install anything. This is because EB will be automatically deleting and adding server instances to your environment, so your manual changes will be lost. You need to configure any changes like installation of the Parse dashboard in your EB config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide an answer to part 2 of your question as I just went through this on AWS for a production Parse Server deployment. I am using the [Parse Server Example 1.4.0](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) as my base and adding mods to the index.js and package.json for this. I originally got everything working following the AWS with Elastic Beanstalk guide. This requires at least Parse Dashboard 1.0.8 because of the fixes to the mounting in express.

In the package.json here is my dependencies list (npm will automatically install these when deploying to AWS):

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "~4.11.x",
  "kerberos": "~0.0.x",
  "parse": "~1.8.0",
  "parse-server": "~2.2.6",
  "parse-dashboard": "~1.0.8"
},
```

Then, in the index.js add the Parse Dashboard:

```
...
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
...
// Added near the end of the file after the createLiveQueryServer
// Try to setup the dashboard
var config = {
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "yourparsedomain" + mountPath,
      "appId": "YOUR_APP_ID",
      "masterKey": "YOUR_MASTER_KEY",
      "javascriptKey": "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY",
      "restKey": "YOUR_REST_KEY",
      "appName": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
      "appNameForURL": "uniquename",
      "production": true
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "user":"user1",
      "pass":"pass1"
    },
    {
      "user":"user2",
      "pass":"pass2"
    }
  ]
};
var allowInsecureHTTP = false;
var dash = ParseDashboard(config, allowInsecureHTTP);
app.use('/dash', dash);
```

If you are not using SSL set allowInsecureHTTP = true;

Now you can access your Parse Dashboard at "yourparsedomain/dash" with user security enabled. The user security is important because you don't want your Master Key getting out in the wild.

Comment: I would add that using the EB CLI is very important. I had all kinds of issues with uploading the zip, etc. But the CLI worked great.

Comment: Thanks so much! I implemented this solution in my app and it works great.  Two questions if I may: 1. Is there any way to use my existing client-sessions instead of the above user security?  2. Can I add my custom header and nav to the dash?  I'm very new to node/express - any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: MayNotBe - According to the docs on GitHub this is the only way they show to add authentication to the Dashboard. This is different from the _User table in your Parse data. This is only for locking down the dash. I don't have an answer on the header, sorry.

Comment: Worked great on the latest parse-server and parse-dashboard. 

Running it locally using http://localhost:1337/dash and from AWS EB's server worked perfectly! Thanks