# Can I use Parse-Dashboard in a node.js app alongside Parse-Server?

Tags: node.js, parse-server

[Parse-Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)

[Parse-Dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard)

[Parse-Server-Example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)

I forked the Parse-Server-Example to create my new app using Parse-Server.

I'm new to node apps and there's not a lot of documentation yet.

Is it possible to use Parse-Dashboard in my app so a user can log in and view the database?

If so, how would I configure the dashboard in `index.js`?

Could it be as easy as this?

`var parseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');`

`var dash = new parseDashboard( {
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "appId": "myAppId",
      "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
      "appName": "MyApp"
});`

If that's the case, how can I navigate to the dashboard view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503946/1824282) worked for me:

```
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
...
// Added near the end of the file after the createLiveQueryServer
// Try to setup the dashboard
var config = {
  "apps": [
    {
      "serverURL": "yourparsedomain" + mountPath,
      "appId": "YOUR_APP_ID",
      "masterKey": "YOUR_MASTER_KEY",
      "javascriptKey": "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY",
      "restKey": "YOUR_REST_KEY",
      "appName": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
      "appNameForURL": "uniquename",
      "production": true
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "user":"user1",
      "pass":"pass1"
    },
    {
      "user":"user2",
      "pass":"pass2"
    }
  ]
};
var allowInsecureHTTP = false;
var dash = ParseDashboard(config, allowInsecureHTTP);
app.use('/dash', dash);
```